# oracle apex 5 LOV Wrong number of columns selected in the LOV SQL bug

Tags: oracle-apex-5, lov

I created a list of values in my APEX app, with query like below:

```
select JMENO as display_value, JMENO as return_value 
  from VW_DISTINCT_JT_PARTY
 order by 1
```

But when I execute the form whereI use the LOV for text field with autocomplete, it shows the error message
[image]

Anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The LOV for a Text Field with Autocomplete item must contain only **one** column, which is used as lookup and display.  When you think about it, it wouldn't make sense for it to work otherwise!

Comment: In that case I can only create the list of values only as query not as shared component. It seems like in this case I cannot use shared component.